# input text isn't updating angular model in one case that is identical to another in the same form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple form (reduced from the actual form to demonstrate the problem):

```
<pre>Name: {{currentChild.name}}</pre>
<pre>Annual College Expense: {{currentChild.annualCollegeExpense}}</pre>
<form name="childForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-minlength="1" ng-model="currentChild.name" ng-required="true">
            <div class="help-block"
                 ng-messages="childForm.name.$error"
                 ng-show="childForm.$submitted || childForm.name.$dirty || (childForm.name.$invalid && childForm.name.$touched)">
                <p ng-message="required" ng-hide="childForm.name.$valid">Your name is required.</p>
                <p ng-message="minlength" ng-hide="childForm.name.$valid">Your name is too short.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Annual Expenses:</label>
            <input type="text" name="annualCollegeExpense" class="form-control" ngModel="currentChild.annualCollegeExpense" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I fire up the form, I see the expected data in the pres at the top of the form.  When I type into the name field, the name in the pre changes.  When I type into annual expense field, the annual expense pre does NOT change.

Since these are IDENTICAL and appear to obey all the usual ng-model rules, i.e., use a . to reference the data in the model, I'm stumped.

Anybody got a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

you used `ngModel` instead of `ng-model` so you should use

```
 ng-model="currentChild.annualCollegeExpense"
```

instead of

```
ngModel="currentChild.annualCollegeExpense"
```

use

```
<input type="text" name="annualCollegeExpense" class="form-control" ng-model="currentChild.annualCollegeExpense" />
```

Comment: You know I just this second looked at the form controller in $scope and didn't see any field.  Which led me to seeing the typo myself.  Too much coffee, too little sleep.  Thanks for the catch.